# How to get HH:MM using pipe in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am using angular 4 for the web application .Here I am passing HOURS to display in the Table list(HH:MM:SS).I want to show only HH:MM in the list.I am passing HH:MM:SS from the database.I used date pipe to show the HH:MM .But it displayed "InvalidPipeArgument: 'Invalid Date' for pipe 'DatePipe'" error. I am fetching both the format string data from db for eg: 543:43:09(HH:MM:SS) and 76:33(HH:MM)
How can i achieve this?

The sample data's maybe

300:56:05

300:56

I want to tranform the data format in to 300:56(HH:MM) format

```
 <span>{{time | date:"hh:mm"}}</span>
```

Comment: Is `time` a string? If so include a complete sample value.

Comment: let me understand, are you receiving the string "HH:MM:SS" from DB and you want to use it as date format?

Comment: Yes..How can i include sample value?

Comment: I am receiving  string "HH:MM:SS" from DB and i want to change it into HH:MM format.

Comment: That's not a timestamp or a date, that's a string. You can't use `time` pipe on strings. Use the slice pipe, as shown in one of the answers.

Comment: Given your edit, try `{{time.split(":").slice(0,2).join(":")}}`.

Comment: Its working!! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A simple way could be using the SlicePipe:

```
Time: <span>{{time | slice:-3}}</span>
```

Doc: https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Enjoy !

Comment: Way cleaner than Igor's answer, should be on top.

Comment: Its working .But here i am facing another issue.The data from db have both HH:MM and HH:MM:SS format.In that case its not working

Comment: @ancy then formalize your data.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary 0 in the slice parameters. For the case of HH:MM if you have the ability to formalize your data in the database then it's the best solution. Else, you can formalize it in your frontend model but it's not very good or split your string by the : character and get the first 2 entries. You can create a custom pipe for handling that last case